# Has one polymorphic associtaion with conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I basically wanted to add a condition in the below mentioned associations

```
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :post, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :head_post, :class_name => 'Post', :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => 'head_post_id'
  end
```

In posts table I have two records for each group which is post and head_post and I am differentiating between those two using a field in group 'head_post_id'

Something like

```
  has_one :post, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => "posts.owner_id != #{self.head_post_id}"
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @User089247 It should return the correct post, group.post should query posts table(owner_type and owner_id) and check if group.head_post_id is not equal to fetched post( that means fetched post should not be head_post )